# In Javascript, is there a click and drag event listener for mobiles?

Tags: javascript, mobile, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener

I've made an Etch-a-Sketch to The Odin Project exercise using flexbox and javascript. But, I've add a change which instead of painting continuously (through a mouseover/hover event), the program only paints when clicking and dragging with the left mouse button. The program works fine, but due to this specific eventListener, it doesn't work for mobile.

I'm new to DOM manipulation and would like to implement one more option, or alternative, that works for mobiles as well. Can anyone give me a tip about an eventListener that could help? Or any idea?

The part of the code I'm talking about:

```
function **paint**(){
//take all the columns been currently been displayed, they represents the 'squares' inside the canvas
let columns = document.querySelectorAll('.canvasColumn');

//for each column taken, add an event listener:
columns.forEach(square => { 

    //a mousemove listener with the event.button of a left click inside it:
    square.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        if(event.buttons == 1) {
         event.preventDefault(); //this cancel the event to propagate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend`, and `touchcancel` events that you can add listeners for as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events.

See also this example paint app: https://rbyers.github.io/paint.html (check the source to see how they are using the touch events).

MDN also has an in depth tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events.